# Were hag stones ever engraved?

Tags: europe, symbols, folklore, celtic

I found a [hag stone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_stone) the other day and am planning on stringing it as an amulet. My research indicates such amulets were in use over much of Europe, particularly Western Europe, as well as Egypt and Russia (not really sure if Russia is considered Europe or Asia).

I know that the [power](https://www.thegypsythread.org/hag-stone-sacred-powerful-magickal/) of these amulets was derived from the stones themselves, not from symbols or sigils like some such objects.[Link](http://journal.sciencemuseum.ac.uk/browse/issue-11/a-history-of-amulets-in-ten-objects/)

That being said, were they ever engraved with symbols meant to enhance their perceived power? Despite reading that they’re common archaeological finds, I’m having difficulty finding ancient examples amongst all the contemporary ones.

I don’t want to carve the stone with Celtic, Nordic, etc symbols if those cultures only wore them plain. Ruins the point of potentially using this in reenactment costumes one day. Any information would be wonderful, thanks!

Comment: @MCW Is it better now? The three links now in the answer have just about everything I’ve found. Unfortunately a lot of articles I wanted to read for research were behind paywalls...

Answer (score 2):

I can't really give more info than what you already said, but based on what I've learned about them from the links you gave here's what I think.

The legend says they come from a knot made of snakes using their saliva . Since it's a natural stone, found and not created, it would feel off carving anything into it as it is said to already be an object of great power. Plus I didn't see any mention of carved ones.

If you want my opinion (even though there are not many facts backing it up), you should leave them natural. Maybe practice your carving in different amulets, but from what I've gathered hag stones were used without being carved. Although it would definitely look cool.